# Webdeploy failure after recycle

Tags: iis-7

I made a SQL error that locked up my database for my web application. I killed the session buy recycling iis , but now I can't publish to webdeploy. Would Recycling the application Would Recycling the application have stopped or affected the webdeploy service as well? I already restarted the webdeploy service to no avail. Error occurs when trying to save save packaged deployment 2 the webdeploy directory. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was not the recycle that caused the service to stop